# Override javascript function on angular using $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using a javascript lib which have many of these functions:

```
var obj = Object.create(var1, var2);

obj.execute({
  success: function(newObj) {
    console.log("Success: " + newObj)
  },
  failure: function(newObj, errorStr) {
    console.log("Error: " + errorStr);
  }
});
```

I want these functions to return promises instead of callbacks, so my first attempt is to wrap them on other functions:

```
$scope.replaceExecute = function(obj){
  var defer = $q.defer();

  obj.execute({
    success: function(newObj) {
      $scope.$apply(function (){
        defer.resolve(newObj);
      });
    },
    failure: function(newObj, errorStr) {
      $scope.$apply(function (){
        defer.reject(newObj, errorStr);
      });
    }
  });
  return defer.promise;
};
```

But I would like to replace the original prototype function instead of creating a new one, so  I have tried this:

```
var origMethod = Object.prototype["execute"];

// Overwrite original function by wrapping it with $q
Object.prototype["execute"] = function() {
  return origMethod.apply(this, arguments)
  .then(function(data){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve(data);
    return defer.promise;
  }, function(err){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.reject(err);
    return defer.promise;
  });
};
```

But when using it, I don't get the newObj object, but a callback method instead:

```
var obj = Object.create(var1, var2);

obj.execute().then(
  function(newObj) {
    // This won't get newObj but some callback methods
    console.log("Success: " + newObj)
  },
  function(error,errorString) {
    // This won't get error but some callback methods
  }
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the promise first, run the method (which will either resolve or reject the promise), but return the promise:

```
Object.prototype["execute"] = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    origMethod.apply(this, arguments)
        .then(function(data){
            defer.resolve(data);
        }, function(err){
            defer.reject(err);
        });
    return defer.promise;
});
```